# How many solutions for the equation $Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5 = 6$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many solutions for the equation $Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5 = 6$ ?

where $0\leq Y_1 \leq 3$ and $1\leq Y_2 \leq3$ and $Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\geq 0$ and $Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5 $ are integers.

---

I tried to apply brute force and got following  equations :

- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 5\quad$ has $21$ Solutions
- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 4\quad$ has $15$ Solutions
- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 3\quad$ has $10$ Solutions
- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 2\quad$ has $6$ Solutions
- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 1\quad$ has $3$ Solutions
- $Y3 + Y4 + Y5 = 0\quad$ has $1$ Solution

---

Am I going right here ?

**EDIT:** Using generating functions gives $106$, but what is the error in above method.

Comment: Add that they are integers.

Comment: From a program I put together, it appears the answer is 106 (if this helps).

Comment: @Mark Yes,I used generating functions and got 106. I'll edit that. But, why above method is not right ?

Comment: What you have noticed is that the number of ways to sum three numbers to make $n$ is $T_{n+1},$ the $(n+1)$st triangular number, which is $\frac 12(n+1)(n+2)$